# How to upload Databases?

Tags: android, ios, cloud, server

What is the best way to store/upload databases from Android and iOS applications?

I have a application that store data in database, i want to upload it to some cloud/server via Wi-fi or cellular internet.

I need an ability to download them after they upload

What are you suggest ?

Thanks

Comment: What is your suggestion? i want to implement it quickly, and not it is  low traffic test  so i would need it for free.

Comment: do you want to ship your app with prepopulated database or get the data from server

Comment: Today i upload database from my ios app  to my "server"  on pc via http post.

I need some server "on-line" or cloud to store data from phone app, with ability to download it or manage data there from my pc.

Comment: You can use parse.com, as per my knowledge and experience it is best platform and API is also easy. OR else you can use webservice as @PramodYadav said.

Comment: So what the parase.com platform  i need to use in my case?

Comment: Yes please check documentation from https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#top/iOS

Comment: Its like a webservice, you have to follow formality of keys and than pass values with use of its API.